# Show only content inside div's background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A div in which I would be sliding in images , I want the images to appear in only a certain area of the div, say a triangle shaped area. The rest of the div should just show whatever is underneath the div.

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    width: 700px ;
    height: 300px ;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: url("img/overlay.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="boxcat" id="websitesbox">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="websitesSlider">
        <img src="img/seanswers.PNG" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
        <img src="img/stories.png" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
        <img src="img/PerfectUpload_1.png" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here I would be sliding in the images into overlay, BUT I don't want the images to show up completely , instead just a part of the overlay div should be covered in the image.
Not sure If I am making any sense. If I am is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try something with CSS-rotations and overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `mask-image` however it isn't widely supported by the browsers.

Here you can read about the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/

And here you can see the support: http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Answer (score 0):

you can next websitesSlider into overlay:

```
<div class="boxcat" id="websitesbox">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="websitesSlider">
             <img src="img/seanswers.PNG" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
             <img src="img/stories.png" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
             <img src="img/PerfectUpload_1.png" alt="Seanswers screenshot">
         </div> 
    </div>    
</div>
```